# VUEJS - Append <tr> element when button pressed

Tags: vue.js, datatable, appendchild

[image: Question picture]

I have a table in my Vuejs project similar to the one that I shared its screenshot above.

My question is; How can I delete a `<tr>` element from the table when the `Delete` button of it is pressed for each row?

On the other hand, I want the `Add` button at the top right of the table to be functional as well. When I click the `Add` button, I want another `<tr>` element to be created at the bottom of the table. However, there should be input fields on this element where the user can enter information for each column. After the user has written the information in each column, that row should be added to the table. How can I do that?

Comment: can you share the related code please ?

Comment: @omerS it's just a hard coded table.

Answer (score 0):

if I am correct you are using `v-for` loop to render all `<tr>`s

then use the v-for with index like `v-for="(obj, index) in objects"` to obtain index

to add use [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add empty row e.g. `objects.push({x: null, y: null})`

to remove use [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) e.g `objects.splice(index, 1)`

just assign those functionalities to respective buttons.

Comment: I haven't used v-for honestly this table is filled hard coded. In the next versions of the project the data will be coming from backend, so I just need to find a way to append child <tr> elements to my view with three input fields. When the three of them is typed by the user, there should be a new <tr> element with those respective texts, a switch and a delete button.

Comment: @YasinDemirkaya `In the next versions of the project the data will be coming from backend` How the data will come axios, ajax ?

Comment: Probably Axios.

Comment: then you obviously have to modify the `array of objects`, so modify it as per my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt this using a data property in your component and then implement two methods: `deleteRow` and `addRow`.

This could be an example code

```js
data() {
  return {
    dataTable: [
      {
        id: 1, 
        code: code1, 
        description: description1,
      },
      {
        id: 2, 
        code: code2, 
        description: description3,
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
methods: {
  deleteRow(id) {
    this.dataTable = this.dataTable.splice(
      this.dataTable.findIndex(item => item.id === id)
    )
  }
  addRow(newRow) {
    // newRow = {id: 3, code: code3, description: description3}
    this.dataTable = [...this.dataTable, newRow]
  }
},
```

Your component will be updated by `Vue.js` reactivity system.

Probably `addRow` method should be called from a modal component where you put the input fields to set `newRow`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to implement something like this in your answer.